# Entropy with Markov Process

Tags: statistics, markov-process, entropy

Can somebody please explain or help me reach an answer to this. I plainly don't know where to start. Sorry for not providing my work because am just confused on what to do. If somebody can please provide explanation with steps in order to understand, would be really appreciate it.

[image]

Comment: The (c) part in the question is weird since, typically, when considering a Markov chain one is interested in the entropy rate and not the conditional entropy at time $n$. In other words, the question tests whether you know to compute standard conditional entropy not that of a Markov chain. Also, the probabilities given in (c) are not the stationary distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional on $X_n = a$, the distribution of $X_{n+1}$ is $a$ with probability $0.7$ and $b$ with probability $0.3$.  Therefore the conditional entropy is
$$
H(X_{n+1} | X_n = a) = -0.7 \log(0.7) - 0.3 \log(0.3) \approx 0.611.
$$
You can do a similar calculation for $H(X_{n+1} | X_n = b)$.  Finally, the definition of $H(X_{n+1} | X_n)$ is
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{P}(X_n = a) H(X_{n+1} | X_n = a) + \mathbb{P}(X_n = b) H(X_{n+1} | X_n = b) \\
= \ &0.4 H(X_{n+1} | X_n = a) + 0.6 H(X_{n+1} | X_n = b)
\end{align*}